# Can I create a separate class for u element

Tags: html, css

I want to underline some text but want the colour of the line different to the colour of the text. As I understand, I need to use `u` element here.

What I have is:

```
<div class="footerr">DRAWING, art 
and illustrations.</div>
```

What I can change it to is:

```
<div class="footerr"><u>DRAWING, 
art and illustrations.</u></div>
```

Now, I can style my text colour using the div class, but how would I style the `u` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't technically have to use the `u` element here. You can use a `span` with a pseudo element (if you need to give IE users the same experience).

```css
.underline {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.underline::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="footerr"><span class="underline">DRAWING, art 
and illustrations.</span></div>
```

Comment: Both  excellent answers. But it can I add  another class and if so how?

Comment: @Ads not sure what you mean by _add another class_? That's what this answer does. Adds a class to the span to style it. You could certainly do that with your `u` element. `<u class="someclasshere">` or target only the `u` in the `footerr` `.footerr > u`

Comment: I see, yes. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the [`text-decoration-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-color) property:

```css
u {
  text-decoration-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="footerr"><u>DRAWING, 
art and illustrations.</u></div>
```

This keeps the text color and changes the underline color.

Comment: Thanks but that would style all  u elements red. Can  I target just that specific u element?

Comment: Note - If you need to support IE, then you will need to find a different way

Comment: @Ads `. footerr  u` targets `u` in `footerr` please read up on the basics of css at least

Comment: @Ads Sure, use any combination of selectors you like to make it more specific. Add a class to the `<u>` elements you want to target for example. What matters is the property.

Comment: @Huangism Is there still someone around that uses IE?

Comment: @j08691 Oh thanks. How do  I add a class to u element?

Comment: Not only IE don't support this. Edge 12-18, Chrome 56, Opera Mini and some others [don't have support for this property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#line-decoration)

Comment: @0stone0 based on [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=text-decoration-color), look at the percentage of those browsers usage. I would consider this a non-issue.

Comment: Yea, for 92.06% of the users this won't be an issue. It's more that people are aware that not *all* browsers support this.

Comment: @j08691 unfortunately some corporations still use it for their internal infrastructure and the general public use of IE11 is currently above the threshold of being killed for the websites my company supports. Hopefully very soon it will die, we have brought this up many times now with them

Comment: @Huangism while that is certainly true, do we, as developers, need to limit what we do for less than 2 percent of users? Since this particular style doesn't seem to be a critical/blocking component, do we just move forward and say "IE11 users won't get the same experience" This is a discussion we have often. I think it makes the choice easier when Microsoft doesn't even support that browser any longer.

Comment: Also a great  answer @j08691. Thanks. If I had enough points I'd give  you  an up vote.

Comment: @disinfor we have already had this conversation internally and everyone wants to drop IE11 but the client who is paying us won't. I don't own the company and the client is an huge international car company. We(my company) will have to wait for time to kill IE11. I am just leaving the IE support as a note so no one is surprised if they discover it. For our company this would have fallen under the graceful degradation category